# How I add dynamically a Map to List in Groovy

Tags: list, dictionary, groovy

I want to dynamically add a map to a list like this:

```
def map = [:];
def list= [];

def n = 10;

n.times{
 map.put("Int I", it);
 list.add(map);
}
println list;
```

result:

```
[[Int I:9], [Int I:9], [Int I:9], [Int I:9], [Int I:9], [Int I:9], [Int I:9], [Int I:9], [Int I:9], [Int I:9]]
```

Actually I expect this:

```
[[Int I:0], [Int I:1], [Int I:2], [Int I:3], [Int I:4], [Int I:5], [Int I:6], [Int I:7], [Int I:8], [Int I:9]]
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: You always add **the same map** to the list. Move the `def map = [:]` into the times closure.

Comment: @cfrick Can you show me an example please?

Comment: @cfrick i got it, Big Thanks!

Comment: another overengineering. a simple `n.times{ list << [ 'Int I':it ] }` would do

Comment: Since we are golfing: `(0..<10).collect{["int i": it]}`